# Linq Matching Pattern

Tags: c#, linq

I have to search a list of strings in CityList and if it contains all  search strings
then it should return true otherwise false.

When i search "London","Dallas" against CityList it should return false,because
"Dallas" is missing in CityList.

```
var CityList=new string[] { "London","Paris","Houston","Mexico","Budapest"}

var search =new string[] {"London","Dallas"};
```

How to rewrite the following ?

```
var result =  CityList.Select(c => c).ToList().FindAll(search.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var hasAll = !search.Except(CityList).Any();
```

By the way, you should never write `something.Select(c => c)`; such a statement will do nothing but make the program a tiny bit slower.

Comment: That's the correct answer, but the other way round (it returns false if some terms of search is in the CityList, and true otherwise). So : 
! search.Except(CityList).Any();

Comment: return something.Select(c => c); is very useful when you want to return an IEnumerable from a List, Collection whatever without returning the actual object. I use it all the time.

Comment: @AZ: That's what the `AsEnumerable` method is for.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var result = search.All(s => CityList.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 3):

You have various possibilities:

```
var result = CityList.Union(search).Count() == CityList.Count();
var result2 = search.All(s => CityList.Contains(s));
var result3 = search.ToList().TrueForAll(s => CityList.Contains(s));
var result4 = CityList.Intersect(search).Count() == search.Count();
```

Comment: The first method won't work if `CityList` has duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

That quite an easy one

```
search.All(c => CityList.Contains(c))
```

All will only satify when all predicates return true, then we check if the citylist contains the item

Comment: My way is faster, since `Except` will build a hash table.

Comment: SLaks' way also uses more memory, since Except will build a hash table. The speed increase does not come for free; it trades more memory for less time. Since memory is generally a cheaper resource than time, this is probably a good tradeoff. But it's worth remembering that performance optimizations usually involve trading one kind of bad performance for another.